Flutter Spotify_sdk - not installed correctly

I installed the package: https://pub.dev/packages/spotify_sdk
Downloaded the ios SDK from github
Dragged the file to XCode




Added the necessary stuff to inf.plist



Tried to get the auth token but

flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ ⛔ connectToSpotify failed with: Spotify app is not installed<…>
this error appears. What have I missed out here?I also added the #import <SpotifyiOS/SpotifyiOS.h> as well.
